# Online pdf content to BufferedInputStream with authentication

Tags: java, selenium, pdf, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to read the content of the pdf which opens in the browser - without success. All the examples I have found online require this step:

```
    URL url = new URL(strURL);
    BufferedInputStream file = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(file);
```

The problem is that I have to authenticate first in the site - then navigate to the pdf location - which opens on a new tab - then I switch to the tab and grab the url.

However, when I pass the url to the code above - it is creating a new request and therefore it has lost the authentication and the site returns code `401-Unauthorized`.

*One important detail - this is an embedded pdf.*

Is there a workaround I can use - such as grabbing the pdf that is already loaded - instead of making a new call? I am out of ideas. Thank you!

**Edit**

One possible workaround I thought about was to turn this setting on Chrome

```
Download PDF files instead of automatically opening them in Chrome    On/Off
```

Is it possible to turn this setting on programatically? Note that I switched the setting on - on my Chrome profile which `Selenium` uses as well - but when the Selenium browser opens this setting is turned off.

This is solved by adding options:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=<path_to_profile>");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

**Update**

***Abhishek Dhoundiyal*** answer is great - the only thing I changed - since I was already authenticated while navigating to the specific page - instead of passing username and password again - I just saved the cookies and load them to the url:

```
Set<Cookie> allCookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
```

Then,

```
URL url = new URL(strUrl);
HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

for(Cookie cookie : allCookies) {
   myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.toString());
}

myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
BufferedInputStream file = new BufferedInputStream(myURLConnection.getInputStream());
```

And finally do something with the pdf i.e.: get the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid `401-Unauthorized`, you need to pass your user credentials.

```
    URL url = new URL("YOUR_URL");

    HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    String userCredentials = "username:password";
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(userCredentials.getBytes());
    myURLConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
    myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

    BufferedInputStream file = new BufferedInputStream(myURLConnection.getInputStream());
    PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(file);
```

**To enable download**

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
    prefs.put("download.directory_upgrade", true);
    prefs.put("download.default_directory", "path-to-download-directory");
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```